# ! Missing endcsname inserted

Tags: missing

Every time I try to insert an image on Markdown and try to Knit, the "! Missing endcsname inserted." error appears, even the image is well located by Markdown, What can I do to solve it?

This is what's appears

```
! Missing endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   protect 
l.219 ...tadistica/imagenes/introduccion/Knit.png}
Error: LaTeX failed to compile Libro-Bioestadistica1.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See Libro-Bioestadistica1.log for more info.
Execution halted
```